# Could not GET 'https://giphy.bintray.com/giphy-sdk/dev/dworks/libs/volleyplus/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, native

I am getting this error when I am trying to build the app,

[image]

I have tried Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project and it didn't work.

Comment: Could you show your build.gradle? Do you have `jcenter()` under `repositories`?